# React-Native - preload scene and prevent unmount

Tags: react-native, preload, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native-router-flux` to navigate inside my `react-native` application. There is a scene which contains `WebView` and its performance is slow because of the re-rendering of the component.

My main screen is full of `anchors` and each of them open the browser, but the problem is that each time the browser need to re-render.

My question is - how to avoid this? The obvious is to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and update the url, but its doesn't work since the scene is re-render each time.

Another issue is that the `WebView` loading takes 5-6 seconds to load url for the first time. There is a way to mount the browser scene with meaning less url (google for example)?

This is my router code:

```js
<Scene key="drawer" component={Sidebar} open={false} initial={this.state.auth} navigationBarStyle={$style.header} type="reset">
                    <Scene key="drawer_root"
                        navigationBarStyle={$style.header}
                        type="reset"
                    >
                        <Scene
                            key="main"
                            component={MainView}
                            animation={I18n.isRTL ? 'leftToRight' : 'horizontal'}
                            renderTitle={this.logoButton}
                            renderLeftButton={ I18n.isRTL ? this.profileButton : this.sidebarButton }
                            renderRightButton={ I18n.isRTL ? this.sidebarButton : this.profileButton }
                            type="reset"
                            initial={true}
                        />
                        <Scene
                            key="browser"
                            component={BrowserView}
                            navigationBarStyle={$style.header}
                            renderTitle={this.logoButton}
                            renderRightButton={ I18n.isRTL ? this.backButtonBrowser : this.emptyFunction }
                            renderBackButton={ I18n.isRTL ? this.emptyFunction : this.backButtonBrowser }
                        />
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
```

The back buttons is just `Action.pop()`.

Comment: I don't understand, why is a single WebView re-rendering from the top? Why does it unmount?

Comment: This is not exactly single, my `WebView` used as a browser - so every time I want to show different URL. 
Why does it unmount I didn't figured out myself, I don't want it to un-mount because it making damage to the performance (each time re-rendering is uesless)..